# Connect to HDInsights SSH through proxy

Tags: azure, ssh, proxy, azure-hdinsight

I've created a Azure HDInsights cluster. I am able to connect via SSH to it from my system. But unable to connect it from my work location (I doubt it is because of my company's proxy settings). I don't have access to change the proxy settings. The command I use to connect is:

`ssh sshuser@hdinsights-ssh.azurehdinsight.net`

Any suggestions to establish a SSH connection?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the result when you connect from your work location?

Comment: Putty supports proxy setting, you could check this [link](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/it-security/use-putty-as-a-secure-proxy-on-windows/).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. My system is unable to resolve the host name (may be DNS problem). I tried the link. Its not working. Also, I cannot find a reliable proxy server online (that is disabled by our Websense :) ). May be I've to ask my admin team to allow traffic to this hdinsight server.

Comment: Yes, I think you should contact your admin. Allow to resolve DNS IP. Also, do you try use Public IP? You could get the IP on your system. I suggest you could try.